# Posting JavaScript Variable to MySQL using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to send a JavaScript variable to PHP but not exactly sure how to do it, a few things have said Ajax but I've never used it before and can't get my head around it. Does anyone know what the easiest way to do this would be? The column which I am attempting to populate in my DB is called 'cogs'.

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#duration-select').change(function() {
var cogs = $('#cogsday').html();

                cogs = cogs.replace(/\D/g,'');

        var x =$('#duration-select').val();


        var y = cogs * x;

        $('#request').removeClass('hidden');

         $('#duration-value').text('Total cost for this duration = ' + (y) + ' cogs');

            if($(this).val() !== '') {


            } else {
                $('#duration-value').text('');

            }
        });
        $('#request').click(function() {

                var cogs = $('#cogsday').html();

                cogs = cogs.replace(/\D/g,'');

        var x =$('#duration-select').val();

        var y = cogs * x;
        $('#total').text(y);

        });

    });
    </script>
```

And the following HTML code:

```
<label id="total"></label>
```

Here is where I am trying to post the data, everything else is posting except for the $cost:

```
<form name="form" method="post">
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <?php

                    if ($row3['availability'] === 'Available') {
                    if (isset($_POST['request'])) {

                        $to_id     = $row3['customerid'];
                        $from_id   = $_SESSION['customerid'];
                        $time_sent = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $subject   = 'Request for ' . $row3['title'];
                        $title     = $row3['title'];
                        $listingid = $listingid;
                        $cost      = $_POST['total']; //posting 0                        

                        $message   = $customer_data['first_name'] . ' ' . $customer_data['last_name']

                        $request = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (to_id, from_id, listing_id, time_sent, subject, message, cogs, messagenumber, title, msgrand) VALUES ('$to_id', '$from_id', '$listingid', '$time_sent', '$subject', '$message', '$cost', '1', '$title', '$randomString')") or die(mysql_error());

                    }


                }


?> 
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="request" value="Yes" /> 
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" value="No" />  

        </div>
    </form>
```

Then I am trying to post the value of the label id=total to my db or the JavaScript variable (y). The problem is that 0 is always being sent to the DB when it should instead be the value that is in the label where the id is total.

Comment: What is the issue then ?

Comment: Syntax error on $message --> at the very end of it you have an extra `'` which is screwing everything up (you are either missing a `'` or you didn't want to have `. ';`)

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com - Sorry, 0 is always being sent to the DB when it should instead be the value that is in the label where the id is total.

Comment: @briosheje - Yes, that was only a mistake upon posting here but is not actually a mistake in the actual code :( removed the most of the $message line as it was irrelevant to the question. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use name parameter for hidden variable and it will be automatically passed to PHP .

```
<label id="total"></label>

<input type="hidden" name="total" id="nameID"/>
```

in javascript below `$('#total').text(y);` write `$('#nameID').val(y);` . Everything will work properly.

You used `total` label , but $_POST recognizes only input type so use `input type=....` instead of a label,divs etc.

Comment: Ok - and then should I still be doing?

$cost      = $_POST['total'];

Comment: @user2244961 yes as your code works properly already , you just had to do change i said using hidden variable.

Comment: @user2244961 , use `<input type="hidden" name="total" id="nameID"/>` Give name="total" So you already have code for that in PHP.

Comment: No, unfortunately I am still getting 0 posted to the DB :(

Comment: @user2244961 Did you check updated answer ? and Do you have Hidden field inside <form> tag ?

Comment: That's what it was, just had to move the hidden field to be inside the form tag, should have known. I wouldn't like to tell you how long I have spent trying to get that working, thanks very much! Really appreciated

Comment: @user2244961 also :  `<?php   if ($ro .... ` This php code should Always at the start , before `<html>` getting ?

Answer (score 0):

## IF YOU REAllY NEED ANSWER REPLY HERE

you have make an input type and its value is to be set by that javascript and then you'll be able to get that $cost value in php code

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="total" id="total">
```

..................

```
$("#total").val(y);
```

Comment: `$(#total").val(y);` Syntax error , " missing before #

Comment: Check Edit history yours and mine. I gave answer before you. :) By the way nice joke

Comment: you replied me first then you edited your answer its very clear any one can see that and you commented on me just because when i correct the typing error my edit will be newer then yours.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to send the variables....

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="name" placevalue="Enter you name" required /><br><br>
<input type="text" id="email" class="email" placevalue="Enter you name" required /><br><br>
<button id= "det_submit" onclick="submit_det()"> Submit </button>

<script>
    function submit_det() {
       var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
       var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

       if(name != "" && email != "") {  
        $.post(
            'xx.php',
               { 
                 name : document.getElementById("name").value,
                 email1 : document.getElementById("email").value,
               },
               function(data){
                   alert(data);
                });

        } else {
            alert("empty");
        }
    } 
</script>
```

here is xx.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email1'])) {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email1'];

                //code to insert into your database......       
        }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a ID and Name for hidden parameter like this

```
<label id="total"></label
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name"/>
```

and in jQuery edit the code like this

```
$('#total').text(y);  
$('#nameID').val(y);
```

hope that it will work